# Why my count is not working? my count_1 and count_2 are not being counted

Tags: python, count

balance = 600

count_1=0

while True:

```
 option = input("Press (A) Make a deposit, (B) Make a withdrawal, (C) Balance report, (D) exit: ")
if option == "A" or option == "a":
  def deposit(count_1):
    deposit = int(input("Enter amount to be deposited: "))
    if deposit < 0:
      print("Please enter a valid number")
      return balance
    else:
      new_balance = balance + deposit
      print("Amount left in your account MXN: " + str(new_balance))
      count_1 += 1
      return (new_balance)
  balance = deposit(count_1)

elif option == "C" or option == "c":
  print("Deposits made: ", count_1 )
  print("Withdraws made: ", count_2 )
  print("Current Balance: ", balance)
```

MY OUTPUT:

Press (A) Make a deposit, (B) Make a withdrawal, (C) Balance report, (D) exit: a

Enter amount to be deposited: 500
Amount left in your account MXN: 1100

Press (A) Make a deposit, (B) Make a withdrawal, (C) Balance report, (D) exit: c

Deposits made:  0

Current Balance:  1100

Comment: please make your code and the problem separate

Comment: you have lot of mistake in your code. even count_2 is not defined. please define it and tell me what count_2 do. then I will give an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `count_1` as an argument to a function, this means it will only be changed INSIDE it, the passed global value will be the same. This is example of your code:

```py
option = 'a'
count_1 = 0

if option == 'a':
    def deposit(count_1):
        count_1 += 1
        print("Within a function", count_1)
    deposit(count_1)

print("Out", count_1)
```

Output:

```
Within a function 1
Out 0
```

What you WANT to do is to change the GLOBAL attribute. You can either change it inside the function or return it with `new_balance` and change it after `deposit()` function was called. Try 2:

```
option = 'a'
count_1 = 0

if option == 'a':
    def deposit():
        global count_1 # Points on global variable
        count_1 += 1
        print("Within a function", count_1)
    deposit()

print("Out", count_1)
```

Output:

```
Within a function 1
Out 1
```